# drupal_json_output() output ascii

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a module that populate commerce cart product titles.
The function looks like this:

```
   function spcart_get(){    
  global $user;
$order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
//var_dump(commerce_line_item_load(176)->line_item_label);
$line_item_id_sp;
$cart_product_array = array();
for ($i=0 ; $i < sizeof($order->commerce_line_items['und']); $i++){
    $line_item_id_sp = $order->commerce_line_items['und'][$i]['line_item_id'];
    $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($line_item_id_sp);
    $cart_product_array[] = commerce_product_load($line_item->commerce_product['und'][0]['product_id'])->title;
}

$output = (object) array('products' => $cart_product_array);
return drupal_json_output($output);
}
```

but the output of the function is in ascii:
{"products":["\u05d0\u05d5\u05e8\u05d6","\u05d0\u05d5\u05e8\u05d6"]}

I want that the output json will be un regular UTF-8 letters...
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[drupal_json_output](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7) actually echos out the code its self so you don't need to return it's output, but you do need to exit after calling it:

```
drupal_json_output($output);
drupal_exit();
```

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem but certainly won't hurt...

Answer (score 0):

You can probably blame [`drupal_json_encode_helper()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21json-encode.inc/function/drupal_json_encode_helper/7), and the fact that you're running a PHP version < 5.3. That function is used in place of `json_encode()` for earlier versions of PHP, and, rightly or wrongly, escapes unicode characters in the way you're describing.

If I recall correctly you're right, this is an unnecessary (and evidently annoying, sometimes) step. JSON's preferred encoding is UTF-8, and there are only [one or two forbidden characters](http://www.json.org/).

You can probably get around it by using plain old `echo json_encode($output);` instead.